# Envío de correo desde WebForms

Tags: c#, email, webforms, combobox

Cuando envío un e-mail no me aparece la información que hay en 2 Dropdownlist sino el identificador

[image: salida de correo]

```
    [![var carga = from ra in contexto.][1]][1]RADICACIONES
                join td in contexto.TIPO_DOCUMENTOS on ra.ID_TIPO_DOC equals td.ID_TIPO_DOC

                select new
                {
                    nombre = td.NOMBRE_TIPO_DOC
                };
    correo.Subject = "Número de radicación" + txtId.Text;
    correo.Body = "Número de radicación:" + txtId.Text + "<br/> "
                + "Asunto:" + txtAsunto.Text + "<br/> "
                + "Categoria:" + cmbCate.SelectedValue + "<br/> " + "<br/> "
                 + "Tipo de documento:" + cmbTipoDoc + "<br/> " + "<br/> "
                 + "Tipo de documento:" + carga + "<br/> " + "<br/> "
                 + "Fecha de radicación:" + txtFecha.Text+ "<br/> ";
    correo.IsBodyHtml = true;
```

Este es el cuerpo del correo, tampoco he podido capturar el numero de radicación que es un autoincremental, y si tienen un pequeño ejemplo de como aplicar estilo al correo se lo agradeceria, estas son las manera en que lo he intentado

Comment: en esta línea:  + "Tipo de documento:" + carga + "<br/> " + "<br/> " presiona un punto luego de carga y dime ¿Qué sale en el intellisense?

Answer (score 0):

estas llamando al objeto, tienes que obtener la propiedad
`cmbTipoDoc.SelectedValue`
y si quieres el texto
`cmbTipoDoc.Text`

Answer (score 0):

La opción que buscaba era

.SelectedItem.Text

Answer (score 0):

Con respecto a los estilos no creo que sea muy complicado, ya tienes definido que el cuerpo del mensaje acepta html, es cuestion de ponerle `css` por ejemplo:

```
correo.Body = "<div style="border-bottom: 1px solid #ccc; text-align: right; width: 100%;">Número de radicación: <strong>" + txtId.Text + "</strong></div>"
                + "<h3>" + txtAsunto.Text + "</h3> "
                + "<p>Categoria:" + cmbCate.SelectedValue + "<br/> " + "<br/> "
                 + "Tipo de documento:" + cmbTipoDoc + "<br/> " + "<br/> "
                 + "Tipo de documento:" + carga + "<br/> " + "<br/> "
                 + "Fecha de radicación:" + txtFecha.Text+ "<br/></p> ";
```

En realidad puede ser cualquier estilo que se te ocurra